# There was a problem during the compilation process of my STM32 Project

Tags: stm32, stm32cubeide

make[1]: *** [Drivers/STM32L1xx_HAL_Driver/Src/subdir.mk:76: Drivers/STM32L1xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l1xx_hal_flash.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [Drivers/STM32L1xx_HAL_Driver/Src/subdir.mk:76: Drivers/STM32L1xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l1xx_hal_flash_ramfunc.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Drivers/STM32L1xx_HAL_Driver/Src/subdir.mk:76: Drivers/STM32L1xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l1xx_hal_dma.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Drivers/STM32L1xx_HAL_Driver/Src/subdir.mk:76: Drivers/STM32L1xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l1xx_hal.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Drivers/STM32L1xx_HAL_Driver/Src/subdir.mk:76: Drivers/STM32L1xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l1xx_hal_flash_ex.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Drivers/STM32L1xx_HAL_Driver/Src/subdir.mk:76: Drivers/STM32L1xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l1xx_hal_cortex.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Drivers/STM32L1xx_HAL_Driver/Src/subdir.mk:76: Drivers/STM32L1xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l1xx_hal_exti.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Drivers/STM32L1xx_HAL_Driver/Src/subdir.mk:76: Drivers/STM32L1xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l1xx_hal_crc.o] Error 1
make: *** [makefile:93: all] Error 2
"make -j8 all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

14:37:45 Build Failed. 10 errors, 0 warnings. (took 2s.850ms)

I am expecting to be able to build my project without running into these compilation errors.

Comment: Has it ever worked? Have you changed something? Are you using CubeIDE? What OS are you using? Have you tried logging out and in again?